# How to safely terminate a tensorflow program running on multiple GPUs

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow

I have implement a network using tensorflow. The network is trained on 4 GPUs. When I hit <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>, the program crashed the nvidia driver and created zombie process named "python". I am not able to kill the zombie process, neither can I reboot ubuntu system by `sudo reboot`.

I am using a FIFO queue and a thread to read data from binary files.

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
t = threading.Thread(target=load_and_enqueue, args=(sess,enqueue_op, coord))
t.start()
```

After I call `sess.close()`, the program won't stop and I see:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:244] PoolAllocator: After 0 get requests, put_count=4033 evicted_count=3000 eviction_rate=0.743863 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:244] PoolAllocator: After 0 get requests, put_count=14033 evicted_count=13000 eviction_rate=0.926388 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0
```

It seems GPU resource is not released. If I open another terminal, `nvidia-smi` command won't work. Then I have to brutally restart system by:

```
#echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
#echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

I know `sess.close` may be too brutal. So I tried using dequeue operation to empty the FIFO queue, then:

```
while iteration < 10000:
  GPU training...

#training finished

coord.request_stop()
while sess.run(queue_size) > 0:
  sess.run(dequeue_one_element_op)
  print('queue_size='+str(sess.run(get_queue_size_op)))
  time.sleep(1)
coord.join([t])
print('finished join t')
```

This method does not work either. Basically, the program can not terminate after max training iteration is reached.

Comment: Have you found solution to this problem? I don't even use FIFO queue or separate thread and still have this problem.

Comment: @Adi No. I end up not using multiple GPUs. :(

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/658

This solved the problem:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

Comment: Actually that does not solve the problem. You method will restrict the program to use only one GPU, but I would like to speed up with multiple GPUs